# second time model changes in codefirst

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I initially generated configuration and Initialcreate classes successfully by mapping the model.

Now I changed the model (by adding one more property) and tried to execute below commands in project manager console.

The commands I have tried:

```
PM> add-migration

cmdlet Add-Migration at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name: Configuration
Scaffolding migration 'Configuration'.
The Designer Code for this migration file includes a snapshot of your current Code First model. This snapshot is used to calculate the changes to your model when you scaffold the next migration. If you make additional changes to your model that you want to include in this migration, then you can re-scaffold it by running `Add-Migration Configuration` again.

PM> update-database -verbose

Using StartUp project 'Demo'.
The project 'Demo' failed to build.
PM>
```

When I tried to execute `add-migration` command then it generated a partial class with same name as Configuration.cs. Now I found two Configuration files but inheritance is different between both classes. What should I do  or what am I doing in wrong manner?

After that I executed the commands again with different name and it worked but when I executed the command Update-database then received an error which I mentioned below:

Table `registeration` already exists

Comment: Try deleting two migration files and run `add-migration` again.

Comment: it says Table registeration already exist.

Comment: and one problem which i am facing is that it deletes all data if i try to delete that table. can't it execute the alter table commands.

Comment: Try `add-migration YourMigrationName -force`

Comment: thank you. please mark your comment as answer.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Comment: sorry to late reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
add-migration YourMigrationName -force
```